# Is it bad design to have 2 full text indexes and one normal index for mysql table?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, full-text-indexing

I have a product table where I have created the following indexes:

- product_category column full text index: I want to be able to retrieve products by category faster.
  Example of a field value: ["Clothing >> Women's Clothing >> Women_Tops >> Women_TShirtsTops >> Candies by Pantaloons Shirts"]
- title full-text index: Allow user to search the product by title
- price index normal: Allow for faster sorting by price
- Primary index is automatically generated on product_id

Everything is working fine but I just wanted to get advice on is a bad design choice to have so many indexes in one table? As the table size grows up to 5 million, would it cause any performance issues just because of having multiple indexes?

Comment: There's not enough information to make that determination.

Comment: Indexes speed up SELECT and related queries. If you're making a lot of updates then lots of indexes could adversely impact performance.. If your tables are mostly static then you won't see that issue. You'll have to profile your application to see what the effects are.

Comment: What's important is making the system of applications observable so that when things go awry, it won't take a rocket scientist to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: If you need all indexes for fast queries, then you need them. The downside of an index (apart from disk space and ram usage) is that any data change will become a notch slower. That may be imperceptible at first, but the more indexes you create on a table the dent in performance becomes more apparent. Now, to answer the question, you'll need to benchmark it. Try it out with a low load (updates + insert + delete + select), then ram it up, until you find out how much load it can support

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you for the response. Any suggestion or resources for mysql on how can I monitor the performance of a table, that is the ram or disk space it takes up or if the performance is negatively affected?

Comment: As a benchmark tool I use JMeter. It's free and should be easy to learn in a few hours for a developer. It has a simple interface and allows you to increasingly [and automatically] apply load to a database (or other server) until it reaches breaking point. It produces graphs where you can clearly see how the response time deteriorates according to the load.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - (Voting to Reopen because the handling of multiple indexes, especially FULLTEXT, involves 'fact', not just 'opinion'.)

Comment: @Rick I trust you'll also take issue with the others who voted to close this question. The only 'fact' that's relevant is that the system needs to be profiled. Since we can't do that and we don't have that data we're left with opinion.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular - Yes.  I picked on you because I can tag a Comment with only one person.  (And you were presumably first.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it is OK to have multiple indexes.  But, except for rare situations, only one index will be used for one `SELECT`.

An FT index, if appropriate, will be used first.  It mostly does not matter if you have any other indexes.

If the query is using FT index, the index on price for ordering will *not* be used.

An `INSERT` has some extra overhead if there are extra indexes.  But usually the indexes are worth having.  That is, don't avoid adding indexes just because of the table size of Insert activity.  Do avoid adding indexes that won't be used.

If we could see a sampling of your queries, we might be able to provide more details.

I use MySQL's slowlog for identifying queries that are having the most impact on the system.  But no tool will tell you how to speed up a slow query.